# How to display a picture instead of the console window on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am building a DLP 3D printer based on a raspberry pi. The mechanical part is working fine so far. Now I am looking for a way to send static .png images to my DLP Beamer via HDMI using Python.
Which would be the best solution for this problem?

Currently my Raspberry Pi is booting to console and I am connecting via SSH.
As a Python and Raspberry Pi beginner it is a bit difficult for me to choose the right approach which suits to my requirements.

Using Google I found:
framebuffer imageviewer //seems to need root
Dispmanx
pygame

Is there any easier solution maybe with a small example?
I would be very grateful for your help!

Comment: This is more of a question for [superuser](https://superuser.com). I think the easiest way would be to install a full fledged desktop environment -- your PI is powerful enough to handle the workload

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://raspberrycompote.blogspot.de/2012/12/low-level-graphics-on-raspberry-pi-part_9509.html) is a good blog that describes what you want to do using the C language. You should give it a read.